# Division of two numbers not storing properly as a double in Java

Tags: java

I declared a variable as a double in java from two figures and it doesn't seem to be coming up properly in the output. For instance, my runs figure was 18, the balls figure was 21, however when printed to screen, the strikerate variable only displayed as 0.0. Can anybody see my issue here? :)

```
    double strikerate = runs/balls;


    System.out.println(runs);
    System.out.println(balls);

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Strikerate: " + strikerate);
```

Comment: what is the type of runs and balls

Comment: When you divide two integers you get an integer.

Answer (score 4):

`int` division will result in `int` value, you need to cast it to (double)

```
double strikerate = ((double)runs)/balls;
```

Comment: @immibis AVOID Answering in comment!!

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
 double strikerate = (double) runs/balls;
```

Comment: Oh.. I see. But why ?? Try to explain why your code works. Mere code is not an answer.

Comment: because int/int so... need to be cast into double